# How can i put two forms build in one module to two URLs

Tags: forms

I am very new to drupal and working with D7

I have created two form with a custom module. mysite.com/custom is showing both the forms at the same time

I want each of the form to be shown with 2 different URLs. eg mysite.com/custom1 eg mysite.com/custom2

How is it possible.OR is it not possible at all. am i totally wrong in understanding how the module and forms work?

code

```
function custom_menu() {
  $items['custom'] = array(
      'title' => t('Custom'),
      //'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page callback' => 'custom_page_callback',
      //'page arguments' => array('custom_form'),
      //'access arguments' => array('custom module'),
      'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

  return $items;
}

function custom_page_callback() {
  $build = array();

  // Render your two forms here.
  $build['form_one'] = drupal_get_form('custom_form');
  $build['form_two'] = drupal_get_form('custom_second_form');

  return $build;
}
/**
 * Our custom form.
 */
function custom_form($form, &$form_submit) {
  $form['title'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Give a title'),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['name'] = array(
      '#name' => t('Give a Name'),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#required' => FALSE,
      '#maxlength' => 25,
      '#size' => 10,
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
      '#value' => 'Add',
      '#type' => 'submit',
  );
  return $form;
}
/**
 * Our custom form second.
 */
function custom_second_form($form, &$form_submit) {
  $form['title'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Give a title'),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
      '#value' => 'Add',
      '#type' => 'submit',
  );
  return $form;
}
```

Thanks all

Comment: Please post your code in question, so we can answer your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have to make small change on function custom_menu.

Try this code.

```
function custom_menu() {
  $items['custom/first'] = array(
      'title' => t('Custom'),
      //'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page callback' => 'custom_page_first',
      //'page arguments' => array('custom_form'),
      //'access arguments' => array('custom module'),
      'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  $items['custom/second'] = array(
      'title' => t('Custom'),
      //'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page callback' => 'custom_page_second',
      //'page arguments' => array('custom_form'),
      //'access arguments' => array('custom module'),
      'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show two forms in two different pages, just define two menu items.

```
function custom_menu() {
  $items['custom'] = array(
    'title' => 'Custom form #1',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('custom_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

  $items['other_custom'] = array(
    'title' => 'Custom form #2',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('custom_second_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

As side note, the content of the "title" and "description" are not passed to `t()`, as I did.